# Levenberg-Marquardt for solving transformation matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, jacobian

Given a set $V$ of $N$ known vectors
    $\textrm{V} = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x_1 &  & x_N\\
  y_1 & \cdots & y_N\\
  z_1 & & z_N\\
  1 & & 1\\
  \end{bmatrix}$ to which a transformation $M$ is applied  $ \textrm{M} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \cos{\psi}\cos{\phi} & -\sin{\psi}\cos{\theta} + \cos{\psi}\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta} & \sin{\psi}\sin{\theta} + \cos{\psi}\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta} & t_x\\
 \sin{\psi}\cos{\phi} & \cos{\psi}\cos{\theta} + \sin{\psi}\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta} & -\cos{\psi}\sin{\theta} + \sin{\psi}\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta} & t_y\\
 -\sin{\phi} & \cos{\phi}\sin{\theta} & \cos{\phi}\cos{\theta} & t_z
 \end{bmatrix}$,
is it possible to solve for the parameters $\beta = \begin{bmatrix} \theta\\ \phi\\ \psi\\ t_x\\ t_y\\  t_z\end{bmatrix}$ if a noisy observation $V^\prime$ of the resulting transformation is obtained by iteratively applying the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm? What would be the form of the Jacobian $J$? Would the partial derivative of each row of $M$ be taken independently since each term in $V^\prime$ is a linear combination of $V$ and $M$?

Comment: Are these Euler angles? May I suggest reformulating with quaternions? This may get your life easier when dealing with numerical methods and you can re-convert to Euler angles for suer interaction purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

$$
\Lambda(\beta)  =(V'-M(\beta)V)
$$

With $\Lambda$ denoting the "error" matrix. Then: $f(\beta)=\text{trace}(\Lambda^T \Lambda)$ is a scalar you want to minimize.

So you can just use:
$$
\beta_{k+1} = \beta_{k}-\frac{\nabla f}{||\nabla f^||^2}f(\beta_{k}) 
$$

In this case:
$$
\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \psi}\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t_x}\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t_y}\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t_z}\end{bmatrix}
$$

To use Levenberg-Marquart you would need to propose a different funcction to minimize, which could be done with a similar logic.

Comment: Mefitico, thank you for your help thus far. I have been trying to calculate $\nabla f$ by hand, but due to the large number of terms after taking the trace, I am going to trust Mathematica and MATLAB results for now. Could you help now with the form of $||\nabla f||^2$? If $\nabla f$ is a column vector, what are the dimensions of $||\nabla f||^2$?

Comment: This is just the squared norm of $\nabla f$, so $||\nabla f||$ is a scalar, hence why its in a fraction numerator (and not some kind of matrix inverse).

Comment: So, I just square each term in $\nabla f$ to get $||\nabla f||^2$ and then divide element-wise $\nabla f$ by $||\nabla f||^2$? Or is $||\nabla f||^2$ the norm of the entire vector $\nabla f$?

Comment: Square element-wise, then sum, then divide each element of $\nabla f$ by the result. Another way of writing this operation would be: $[(\nabla f)^T\nabla f]^{-1}\nabla f$.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense now. Thank you very much. I will let you know how I make out.